# Como inserir corretamente uma navbar Bootstrap na view do Codeigniter?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, framework, view

Estou aprendendo Codeigniter e gostaria de saber qual ou quais as formas corretas de inserir uma **navbar** na minha view levando em consideração que ela será inserida por todas as views presentes no sistema.

A minha dúvida é dentro de qual diretório gravar o código da **navbar** e como chamá-la na **view**?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um arquivo chamado "*navbar.php*", por exemplo, e salva-lo dentro de "*application/views/commons*" (o diretorio commons deve ser criado manualmente, pois ele nao existe).

Quando quiser chamar essa navbar em uma view, basta usar:

```
$this->load->view("commons/navbar");
```

Na posição em que deseja dentro do arquivo da view.